# If two processes updating a Collection at a time then which exception will be raised?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, collections

If two processes in an application are updating one `java.util.List` object then which kind of exception will be raised?

Comment: @Jigar: while "Have you tried it?" is often a good response to simple questions, it doesn't really apply in the multithreading realm: the problem is that even if it works just fine in simple tests, it might still break horribly in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the implementation and the exact timing involved, a wide array of effects may happen:

- you might get "lucky" and nothing bad happens (this *might* even be the common case).
- you might get get a `ConcurrentModificationException`
- you might not get an exception and simply lose one of the updates (or both!)
- you might not get an exception and one of the updates might get lost in an endless loop (happened to me with a `HashMap` once, not very likely for simple `List` implementations, but could still be possible)
- you might not get an exception and introduce wrong state in your list (for example one element inserted correctly, followed by a `null` element).

The problem is that reliably *detecting* if a problem occurred isn't much easier than *preventing* those problems from occurring in the first place, but is a lot less useful. So the sane approach is to use a concurrent data structure and/or synchronization, as appropriate.

Comment: +1, though, I would it not call "lucky" if "nothing bad happens", because that can only mean "nothing bad happens as long as he is testing". The most lucky outcome is surely an Exception.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the exact `List` implementation (there are no `java.util.List` objects because it is an interface). `ArrayList` states:

> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: *the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs.*

Comment: +1: The underlying counter it uses to detect ConcurrentModificationException is not volatile. ;) The only way to guarentee this exception is if you modify the ArrayList in the same thread (without using the smae Iterator)

Answer (score 0):

Processes cannot share a List.  However two threads can share a list.

Some Lists support concurrent updating and don't produce an exception.  Other List do not support concurrent updates and may produce an Exception, but this is not guarenteed for all operations.

In short if you want to modify the List and us it in another thread, you should use a thread safe collection.